# Listing currently executing SwingWorker and Stop it

Tags: java, swingworker

I have below SwingWorker;

```
public class WorkerTrying extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

        Statement stmt;
        Connection con;
        ResultSet rs;
        String connectionUrl = "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.131.10;" + "databaseName=SomeDB;" + "user=" + "SomeUser" + ";" + "password=" + "SomeUserPassword" + ";";

        public void closeConnection() throws SQLException{
        stmt.close();
        System.out.println("Closed!!!");
        }

        protected Void doInBackground() throws Exception {

            String query = "Select column1,column2 from Table1"
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");

            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl);
            stmt = con.createStatement();

            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

            while (rs.next()){
              //Doing something...
            }

            return null;
        }

        public void done() {               

        }  
    }
```

As you can see some DB connection and data fetchinbg via While loop in this worker. My problem is DB Queries takes very long time sometimes. I want add STOP button for closing Statements and Connections in SwingWorker and cancel immediatelly itself.

I am trying below stop button but no help;

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
      WorkerTrying workerTrying = new WorkerTrying();
      workerTrying.cancel(true);
    }
```

Also i have 3-4 SwingWorkers. So i must detect which one is currently running first.

Regards.

**==== UPDATE ====**

New Stop button like this;

```
jButtonStop.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            for(SwingWorker workerTrying : _workers){
                 if(!workerTrying.isDone()){
                    try {
                        ((WorkerTrying)workerTrying).closeConnection();
                    } catch (SQLException ex) {
                        Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    }
                    workerTrying.cancel(true);
                 }
            }

       }
   }
});
```

**==== SECOND ISSUE UPDATE ====**

Start button Action Listener just like this;

```
startButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
              public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                  if(jTextField1.getText().equals("")){
                    final SwingWorker workerTrying = new WorkerTrying();
                    _workers.add(workerTrying);
                    workerTrying.execute();
                  }
                  else{
                    final SwingWorker workerTrying2 = new WorkerTrying2();
                    _workers.add(workerTrying2);
                    workerTrying2.execute();  
                  }
                }
});
```

As you can see some condition for which SwingWorker can be execute.

Than Stop button just like this;

```
stopButton.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                for (SwingWorker workerTrying : _workers) {
                    if(!workerTrying.isDone()){
                        try {
                            ((WorkerTrying)workerTrying).closeConnection();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        workerTrying.cancel(true);
                    }
                }
                for (SwingWorker workerTrying2 : _workers) {
                    if(!workerTrying2.isDone()){
                        try {
                            ((WorkerTrying2)workerTrying2).closeConnection();
                        } catch (SQLException ex) {
                            Logger.getLogger(MainGui.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                        }
                        workerTrying2.cancel(true);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
```

If First SwingWorker (workerTrying) executed and try stopping, everythings looks ok. Statement closed and SwingWorker canceled succesfully.

But when second SwingWorker (workerTrying2) executed and wanted to Stop, below exception throwed;

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: testproject.MainGui$WorkerTrying2 cannot be cast to testproject.MainGui$WorkerTrying
```

Comment: As the exception states, you're trying to cast a `WorkerTrying2` to `WorkerTrying`; you store both of those in the worker list and try to cast them unconditionally. You should rather make them implement a common interface that declares `closeConnection()`, or have a common abstract base class with that method, and use that as the type parameter of the worker list.

Answer (score 1):

I used `List` to track all the Workers. And stopped it all. You can try this.

```
 public class SwingT {
    private List<SwingWorker> _workers = new ArrayList<>();
    public SwingT(){
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test Worker");        
        frame.setSize(320, 160);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        JButton btn = new JButton("Add Work");
        btn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                SwingWorker workerTrying = new WorkerTrying();
                _workers.add(workerTrying);
                workerTrying.execute();
            }
        });

        JButton btn2 = new JButton("Stop All");
        btn2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                for(SwingWorker workerTrying : _workers){
                    if(!workerTrying.isDone()){
                        //Close DB Connections
                        ((WorkerTrying)workerTrying).closeConnection();
                        workerTrying.cancel(true);
                    }
                }

            }
        });
        frame.add(btn);
        frame.add(btn2);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new SwingT();

    }

}
```

**UPDATE**

```
public class WorkerTrying  extends SwingWorker<Void, Void> {

public void closeConnection(){
    //Close the connection
    System.out.println("closed");
}

..........
}
```

Comment: I have Statements and DB Connection in doInBackground() method. Is there any way immediatelly close them ?

Comment: i try it but no help. closeConnection() method created in SwingWorker class included stmt.cancel(); When i call this method from button action java says "it must be in try-catch block" than i call your suggestion ((WorkerTrying)workerTrying).closeConnection(); in try-catch block. But stmt not canceled. Waiting 2 min and retrieve all data.

Comment: Statement not getting closed? Did you put the connection object as member and try to close it in `closeConnection`?

Comment: Program go to `closeConnection` but something wrong in there. When trying close Statement it throws exception and waiting long query execution. When While loop complete in SwingWorker program enter `closeConnection` again and successes this time.

Comment: In the while loop, can you update with this  `while (rs.next()){ if( isCancelled()){
      break;
     } ... }`

Comment: I modified While loop as you suggest but no help. If i call `closeConnection` first Done method processes not triggered before query execution i mean SwingWorker cancel method not triggered. If i call SwingWorker cancel method fist, processes in Done method triggered but when `closeConnection` called it throws exception and query results still coming.

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: In EDT.java `processException` catched i think.

Comment: I suggest close the connection first and then put a separate try catch for the while loop will help I guess. I cannot simulate your problem, to do that I need a very big DB entries.

Comment: Ok i have modified stop button again and call `closeConnection` first. But SwingWorker not canceled if we try close the connection first. Something not going good in `closeConnection` but i dont know about what it is :) Btw what do you mean seperate try catch for the while loop ?

Comment: Yes, you can try that. So the `do` function won't throw an exception the process will not be terminated abnormally.

Comment: When `stmt.close();` or `stmt.cancel();` triggered `Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException` throwed. Why we can't close or cancel Statement basically i dont understand :(

Comment: You just close the connection, everything will be closed.

Comment: If we add SwingWorker to list as `final` like `final SwingWorker workerTrying = new WorkerTrying();` `_workers.add(workerTrying);` we can close connection succesfully. But this time i can't handle multiple SwingWorkers. I will add second update to my question soon.